# JSON touch iphone-sdk, send data over request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, serialization

people,
I'm using JSON touch inmy iphone app.
Now I have to send a string and then an array to server, how can I do this?
I get data from json requests succefully, but I have to send some data.
Here is the code I've got so far:

```
-(void)subimtSelection:(int)aNumber
{
    NSString *choiceData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", aNumber];
    NSError *theError=nil;

    [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeString:choiceData error:&theError];
    NSDictionary *jsDic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:choiceData
                                                    forKey:@"selection"];
    //WHAT SHOULD I DO NEXT?


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ASIHTTRequest` to POST string/json data to server:

```
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"http://server.url"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request appendPostData:[yourJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request startSynchronous];
```

If you want to post a string value then try:

```
[request appendPostData:@"key=value"];
```

`ASIHTTPRequest` can be used in asynchronious mode as well.
P.S. I did not tested the code, but it should work.

To post form data you can use `ASIFormDataRequest`, documentation is [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest)